# Spring Boot with Kafka : How to write unit Integration tests excluding kafka configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I am using [spring-kafka](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.kafka/spring-kafka/2.2.6.RELEASE) dependency in my SpringBoot application to use Kafka.

Everything works fine until my Kafka instance is up and running, but the problem is my **unit&integration** tests, they run fine in my local but not in my deployment pipeline (*which is obvious since Application is trying to connect with Kafka instance [in my build pipeline] while running tests and unable to find any*), so end up getting following error :

```
[Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=biz-web-group-test] Connection to node -1 
could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

This is only happening until I have a method annotated with `@KafkaListener` annotation

```
 @KafkaListener(topics = "${biz-web.kafka.message.topic.name}", groupId = "${biz-web.kafka.message.group.id}")
 public void listenToKafkaMessages(ConsumerRecord consumerRecord) {
        // Some Logic
 }
```

As soon as I comment `//` this annotation, test cases work fine.

**Is there a way I can exclude this kafka-related configuration or this annotation while running the unit/integration tests.**

Comment: For integration test, we use [spring-kafka-test](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/master/src/reference/asciidoc/testing.adoc)

Comment: @Barath I don't want to test the Kafka..... my existing integration test cases are failing because of this. and that is my concern.

Comment: Start en embedded kafka broker to be available while running the test case. Thats the use of spring kafka test as you generally wont connect to external kafka during the test lifecycle.

Comment: okay thanks, let me give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, [spring-test-kafka](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/master/src/reference/asciidoc/testing.adoc) is the library to be used in the unit/integration tests.

> **EmbeddedKafkaBroker**: An embedded Kafka Broker(s) and Zookeeper manager. This class is intended to be used in the unit tests.

**EmbeddedKafkaTest.java**

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@EmbeddedKafka(topics= {"test"},count=1,partitions=1)
public class EmbeddedKafkaTest {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());

    @Autowired
    private EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafka;

    private KafkaTemplate<Integer, String> kafkaTemplate;


    @Test
    public void testConsumer() {

        Map<String, Object> producerProps=KafkaTestUtils.producerProps(this.embeddedKafka);
        ProducerFactory<Integer, String> producerFactory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerProps);
        this.kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory);
        logger.info("embedded kafka ",embeddedKafka);
        kafkaTemplate.send("test", "hello");
         Map<String, Object> consumerProps = KafkaTestUtils.consumerProps("demo-group", "true", this.embeddedKafka);
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        ConsumerFactory<Integer, String> cf = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerProps);
        Consumer<Integer, String> consumer = cf.createConsumer();
        this.embeddedKafka.consumeFromAnEmbeddedTopic(consumer, "test");
        ConsumerRecords<Integer, String> replies = KafkaTestUtils.getRecords(consumer);
        Assert.assertTrue(replies.count() == 1);
    }

}
```

However, you can also ignore the kafka processing annotations by excluding the `KafkaAutoConfiguration` in the test cases.

**Note**: This is applicable only if auto configuration is used. In case of custom configuration, ensure dependencies are loosely coupled to ignore the dependency injection issues.

**AppTestWithoutKafka.java**

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=KafkaAutoConfiguration.class)
public class AppTestWithoutKafka {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        System.out.println("context loads");
    }

}
```

Comment: Getting the following error:`o.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn  : Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x100155760160000, likely client has closed socket` and `org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 5341ms for sessionid 0x100155760160001, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect`

Comment: need to debug to find out whats happening. share sample project to reproduce the issue

Comment: Whe you have some dependency from this package: KafkaAutoConfiguration.class. You can't do this: @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=KafkaAutoConfiguration.class).